# Analyzing a Multi-language Project in Sonar

Tags: xml, configuration, multilingual, sonarqube-5.0

I've followed the guidelines from [SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven) to change my project to a multi-language project.
My project has multiple modules for example:
`project_name`
`module1`
`module2`
`module3`
`pom.xml`

I want to run Sonar rules on my java classes as well as the pom.xml files, however only my java quality profile seem to flag broken rules.

I have removed the sonar.language setting and added the `<sonar.sources>project_name</sonar.sources>` but still no joy. In fact I haven't managed to break a single xml rule in my project.

I have also set the quality profiles for both xml and java in Sonar configuration.

Comment: Can you cite the rules/error messages?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample project to understand your configuration and what might be wrong with it?

Comment: @Compass, that's part of my problem really, there's no errors when I build and my xml rule should break when the package name is present. (in other words always) This was just created to get started with a basic xml rule.

Comment: @DavidRACODON-QAConsultant, This is near enough what my project looks like apart from mine having multiple modules. [example project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-java-javascript-maven)
Unfortunately I can't really show much of my project, sorry.

Comment: In this project the pom.xml file is not taken into account because it is not located in <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>.

Comment: is it possible to refer to the entire project, so that I can include that pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the answer was to upgrade to SonarQube 5.0.
I was able to setup the quality profile for XML rules within the same project as my java rules. See the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/SonarQube+Platform)